# "As is the case for" vs. "As is the case with"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

A little search in Google Books indicates both are commonly used, but I cannot see any semantic difference:

> Scholarly research can show how government subsidies benefit mostly
>   the rich, not the poor, as is the case **for** gasoline subsidies in the
>   Islamic Republic of Iran.
>
> As is the case **for** most newly introduced high-tech services,
>   crowdsourcing raises both hopes and doubts, and certainties and
>   questions.
>
> The important point to stress is that a radar imager, like a bat,
>   principally obtains information as a function of distance from the
>   instrument, rather than look direction, as is the case **for** optical
>   systems.
>
> Keeping confidentiality may result in future harm to some identifiable
>   person other than the patient, as is the case **with** the prostitute and
>   her boyfriend and the drug-treatment patient and his girlfriend.
>
> Of the others, uncombined carbon burns with little or no flame, just
>   as is the case **with** pure charcoal and coke.

My best guess is: with "for", it introduces the direct object for comparison; with "with", it introduces the scenario for comparison. So in practical terms, there's no salient difference between them. Do I get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As is the case with...* means *as is also true about...*  If this is the meaning you are looking for, you can always use *with*.  *With* could be used in all of the examples in the above text; I personally would use *with* instead of *for* in all of them.  On the other hand, *with* and *for* are pretty much interchangeable here.

Now, *the case for* also has the meaning of *those facts that support a case*.  So, you might say this:

> The case for using *with* in all of the examples above is consistency.

I'm saying here that consistency is a reason to substitute *with* for *for*.  *The case with...* would be incorrect in this situation.

Comment: Yeah. The word 'case' has the meaning of 'the reason or the arguments', just as is the case with your example. :)

Comment: Case can also have the meaning of situation or context, as in this case.  :)

Comment: That's a case in point of delivering such meaning. :)

Comment: Yes, I intended that to be the case.  LOL  Ok, I'll stop now.