# Meaning of the phrase "as is the case for"

Tags: meaning

Here is the context it was used in:

> As is the case for many countries still suffering wounds from old
>   wars, it may take a long time for these two to settle their
>   differences.

Comment: Your verb tense is wrong: it may take. It may took is an English mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest that you think of this phrase as a fixed expression or an idiom even though I think no dictionary out there actually has an entry for this expression in its database. It still bets me why not. This syntactical construction seems to be very popular in English and probably deserves at least some mention in those dictionaries. And as for the meaning, it simply means typical or usual (or typically or usually, depending on the context). Consider the following example:

> **As is the case with** many technological advancements, they can be used for the good or the bad of society.

Now, let's paraphrase this example using simpler language:

> **It is typical for** many technological advancements that they can be used for the good or the bad of society.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the sentence is discussed in the previous question [“As is the case for” vs. “As is the case with”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79441/as-is-the-case-for-vs-as-is-the-case-with).

However the first part says "many countries" and the second part says "two countries". Also "took" is the wrong part of speech, so I suggest

> As is the case for many countries still suffering wounds from old
>   wars, it may take a long time to settle their differences.

Comment: I don't think there is any contradiction between "many countries" and "two countries". The idea is, I think, that just as is generally the case witn many other countries undergoing the same situation, these two in particular are finding it difficult to settle their differences.

Comment: @Gustavson which two countries? It would be fine if they were mentioned. The context is lacking in the question.

Comment: What I meant to say is that we can easily imagine a context in which the sentence would not be contradictory: they are speaking about two countries and comparing them with others in a similar situation.

Comment: @Gustavson fair enough, it was the question which lacked context.

Answer (score 0):

"As is the case for"  is a formula used to introduce a state of affairs that is typical. You could express the same meaning by "History shows by many examples that it may take a long time to settle differences between countries if they are still suffering wounds from old wars.